# What could cause a td element to ignore style="width:300px"?

Tags: html, css, styles, width

I have this situation:

[image]

As you can see, I have a `td` with the size 28x49px.

To fix this, I tried to set the `width` to `300px` on the element using the developer tools but the browser (Chrome 31) is stubbornly ignoring me.

How is that possible? What could override a width that I set via `style="width:300px"`?

The parent elements (table, tbody and tr) have each a width of 598px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `tbody` element inside of this table. When opening the first one (which has `visibility:hidden;height:0px`), I saw this:

```
<tr><td width="28px"></td><td width="570px"></td></tr>
```

This means that the browser first sees a two-column table body, remembers the sizes and then uses those to layout the second `tbody`, ignoring the width's specified there.

The solution is to get the sizes right in the first `tbody`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
style="width:300px"
```

with this

```
style="width:300px !important"
```